# How to sum values column wise for Array of Arrays in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I am a newbie to Spark and Scala and trying to solve the below problem but couldn't. Please help me with this. Appreciate your help.

The requirement is to sum the values column wise.
The below code generates

```
val first = vlist.map(_.select("value"))
first.map(_.show())
```

Output:

```
    first: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = 
Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[-0.047363, 0.187...|
|[0.043701, -0.114...|
|[-0.006439, 0.031...|
|[0.168945, 0.0639...|
|[0.049805, 0.0664...|
|[-0.054932, -0.11...|
|[0.094727, -0.118...|
|[0.136719, 0.1484...|
|[-0.12793, 0.2812...|
|[-0.071289, -0.07...|
|[0.115234, -0.012...|
|[0.253906, 0.0385...|
|[-0.062988, 0.031...|
|[0.110352, 0.2480...|
|[0.042725, 0.2949...|
|[-0.074219, 0.112...|
|[0.072754, -0.092...|
|[-0.063965, 0.058...|
|[0.083496, -0.007...|
|[0.043945, 0.1767...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[0.045654, -0.145...|
|[0.053467, 0.0120...|
|[0.033203, -0.089...|
|[-0.08252, 0.0224...|
|[0.182617, -0.044...|
|[0.136719, 0.1484...|
|[0.112793, -0.130...|
|[0.096191, -0.028...|
|[-0.007141, 0.004...|
|[0.115234, -0.012...|
|[0.130859, 0.0084...|
|[-0.020874, 0.021...|
|[-0.267578, 0.084...|
|[-0.015015, 0.193...|
|[0.036865, 0.0201...|
|[0.205078, 0.0042...|
|[-0.013733, -0.07...|
|[0.175781, 0.2128...|
|[-0.061279, -0.06...|
|[0.058838, 0.3574...|
+--------------------+
```

The next step should be the sum of all the values column wise. So, I should ideally end up with one row.

I tried the below code:

```
first.toList.transpose.map(_.sum)
```

Output:

```
<console>:183: error: No implicit view available from   
 org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
   first.toList.transpose.map(_.sum)
```

Also, I tried dividing the values into separate columns(took only 4 columns for testing purpose) and applied agg function which didn't work as well like below:

```
    var table = first
for (i <- 0 to 3) {
    table = table.map(_.withColumn("vec_" + i, $"value"(i)))
}


var inter = table.map(_.drop("value"))
inter.map(_.show())

var exprs = inter.map(_.columns.map(_ -> "sum").toMap)
inter.agg(exprs)
```

Output:

```
table: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = 
Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])
inter: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = 
Array([vec_0: double, 
vec_1: double ... 2 more fields], 
[vec_0: double,
 vec_1: double ... 2 more fields])
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    vec_0|    vec_1|    vec_2|    vec_3|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|-0.047363|   0.1875| 0.002258| 0.173828|
| 0.043701|-0.114258| 0.067383|-0.060547|
|-0.006439| 0.031982| 0.012878| 0.020264|
| 0.168945| 0.063965|-0.084473| 0.173828|
| 0.049805| 0.066406|  0.03833|  0.02356|
|-0.054932|-0.117188| 0.027832| 0.074707|
| 0.094727|-0.118652| 0.118164| 0.253906|
| 0.136719| 0.148438| 0.114746| 0.069824|
| -0.12793|  0.28125|  0.01532|-0.046631|
|-0.071289| -0.07373| 0.199219|-0.069824|
| 0.115234|-0.012512|-0.022949| 0.194336|
| 0.253906| 0.038574|-0.030396| 0.248047|
|-0.062988| 0.031494|-0.302734| 0.030396|
| 0.110352| 0.248047| -0.00769|-0.031494|
| 0.042725| 0.294922| 0.019653| 0.030884|
|-0.074219| 0.112793| 0.094727| 0.071777|
| 0.072754|-0.092773|-0.174805|-0.022583|
|-0.063965| 0.058838| 0.086914| 0.320312|
| 0.083496|-0.007294|-0.026489| -0.05957|
| 0.043945| 0.176758| 0.094727|-0.083496|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
only showing top 20 rows
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    vec_0|    vec_1|    vec_2|    vec_3|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 0.045654|-0.145508|  0.15625| 0.166016|
| 0.053467| 0.012024|  -0.0065| 0.008545|
| 0.033203|-0.089844|-0.294922| 0.115234|
| -0.08252| 0.022461|-0.149414| 0.099121|
| 0.182617|-0.044922| 0.138672| 0.011658|
| 0.136719| 0.148438| 0.114746| 0.069824|
| 0.112793|-0.130859| 0.066895| 0.138672|
| 0.096191|-0.028687|-0.108398| 0.145508|
|-0.007141| 0.004486|  0.02063| 0.010803|
| 0.115234|-0.012512|-0.022949| 0.194336|
| 0.130859| 0.008423| 0.033447|-0.058838|
|-0.020874| 0.021851|-0.083496|-0.072266|
|-0.267578| 0.084961| 0.109863| 0.086914|
|-0.015015| 0.193359| 0.014832|  0.07373|
| 0.036865| 0.020142|  0.22168| 0.155273|
| 0.205078| 0.004211| 0.084473| 0.091309|
|-0.013733|-0.074219| 0.017334|-0.016968|
| 0.175781| 0.212891|-0.071289| 0.084961|
|-0.061279|-0.068359| 0.120117| 0.191406|
| 0.058838| 0.357422| 0.128906|-0.162109|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
only showing top 20 rows
res4164: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
exprs: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Array(Map(vec_0 -> sum, vec_1 -> sum, vec_2 -> sum, vec_3 -> sum), Map(vec_0 -> sum, vec_1 -> sum, vec_2 -> sum, vec_3 -> sum))
<console>:189: error: value agg is not a member of Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]
       inter.agg(exprs)
             ^
```

Please help me with this.

I am sure there should be an easy way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Adding Sample input and output.

Sample Input :

```
first: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = 
Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])

        value
        1,2,3,4,5,6 7,8
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

        value 
        1,2,3,4,5,6 7,8
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Sample Output :

```
first: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = 
Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])

        value
        2,4,6,8,10,14,16

        value
        2,4,6,8,10,14,16
```

Comment: Do you need to work with an array of dataframes?

Comment: Yes....I need the sum for all the array of data frames

Comment: Can you include the schema of the input dataset in your question? Do you want to sum the "columns" in `value` column? Is `value` a struct? Please show 10 rows as input and show an expected result. Edit your question and add the missing information. Thanks!

Comment: Yes...I want to sum the values of the "Value" Column (column wise). No Struct declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked. Thanks for the people who spent time on this. Appreciate it.

```
val first = vlist.map(_.select("value"))
first.map(_.show())
var table = first
for (i <- 0 to 3) {
    table = table.map(_.withColumn("vec_" + i, $"value"(i)))
}


var inter = table.map(_.drop("value"))
inter.map(_.show())

//var exprs = inter.map(_.columns.map(_ -> "sum").toMap)
//inter.agg(exprs)

**val tab = inter.map(_.groupBy().sum())
tab.map(_.show())**


first: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])
table: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([value: array<double>], [value: array<double>])
inter: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([vec_0: double, vec_1: double ... 2 more fields], [vec_0: double, vec_1: double ... 2 more fields])
tab: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([sum(vec_0): double, sum(vec_1): double ... 2 more fields], [sum(vec_0): double, sum(vec_1): double ... 2 more fields])
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        sum(vec_0)|        sum(vec_1)|        sum(vec_2)|        sum(vec_3)|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|2.5046410000000003|2.1487149999999997|1.0884870000000002|3.5877090000000003|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
|        sum(vec_0)|        sum(vec_1)|sum(vec_2)|        sum(vec_3)|
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
|0.9558040000000001|0.9843780000000002|  0.545025|0.9979860000000002|
+------------------+------------------+----------+------------------+
res325: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the aggregation methods, which has got function by name 'sum' which does the aggregation column wise.

```
df.agg(sum("col1"), sum("col2"), ...)
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Well that's great if you have solved your problem. After converting "Value" column to a dataframe of different columns as mentioned above. Just do the following.

```
val finalDf = df.groupBy().sum()
```

finalDf is the dataframe containing the sum of values column-wise.

Comment: will this work for a map of value dataframes? Do you know how to merge different data frames of values into one after summing?

Comment: you mean you want to convert back to that dataframe which contains only one column "value" ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use 'posexplode' to explode the array with index. Then you could have grouped and summed by index.